# Define SQL field relationships when running a query in R

Tags: sql, r, relational-database, rodbc

Setting:
RODBC package loaded
SQL connection

How to:
Extract data from the SQL db from two different tableS which are related.
How to define the relation when running a query?

Comment: I don't think you can have *"relationships"* between objects in R.

Comment: So that means that I have to define the relationship in the query always? When I extract related info of multiple fields from different tables?

Comment: What package are you using to access SQL db.

Comment: The RODBC package. I can access the db tables and thus the fields. I'm now struggling how to extract info from different tables and fields in such way that the relation is kept

Comment: As it stands, this post will be closed as "Too broad". Read about XY problem, tell us what we are trying to achieve by keeping relationships within R. Usually, we extract data into R object(data.frame?) using some SQL package, then manipulate data.

Comment: Ok I will rephrase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127355/discussion-between-zx8754-and-pdg).

Comment: Can't close question